Mains Electrical Safety: Does the socket have to be fused to that of the supply if it's not rated for that current?
In the context of single phase power distribution:
32 x IEC C14 Sockets, connected to an appropriate sized cable fed from a 32A MCB/RCBO.
C14 sockets have integrated fuse at 10a to protect downstream cable and devices.
If the C14 socket itself is not rated for 32a, does it have to be protected using a 10a fuse, in a 32a rated fuse holder?

this is a cursed connector. perhaps use C13 instead?
